# php session destroy issue in specific server

Tags: php, session, cloud, session-variables, session-cookies

I am creating 3 sessions and destroying with proper functions. However it throws weird issue to me where in Internet explorer, it doesn't destroy session, in firefox and chrome, I have to refresh the page twice. Here is the simple code I am using to check:

**login.php**
(This is to create sessions)

```
if(isset($_POST['create_session'])){
$_SESSION['user_id'] = '1';
$_SESSION['first_name'] = 'first name';
$_SESSION['last_name'] = 'last name';

echo "Session Created Successfully! Click <a href='index.php'>here</a>";
}

?>


<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="submit" value="Create Session" name="create_session">
</form>
```

**index.php**
(This is to check whether session has been created properly or not)

```
<?php
session_start();

echo "<pre>";print_r($_SESSION);

echo "<a href='logout.php'>logout</a>";    

?>
```

**logout.php**
(This is how I destroy the session)

```
<?php

session_start();
session_destroy();
session_write_close();    
header("location:login.php");

?>
```

**Functions I have tried with referring stackoverlow itself are as blow:**

1. session_cache_limiter("nocache");
2. session_cache_expire(0);
3. session_write_close();
4. ob_flush();

However none of the solution worked.

I am using cloudsites from liquid web to host above code, in case any one has faced same issue from same service provider. Their support says they use opcache engine in cloud, in case opcache is the reason, not sure about that.

It's a deadlock for me to host a project, so right solution will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

try this please:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    session_unset();
    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();
    header("Location: http://example.com");

?>
```

This should be enough to solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I have already tried this way as first attempt, however it doesn't work. Can you please suggest some other way? Or the reason behind this issue?

Comment: have you tried `$_SESSION = array();` see my updated answer.

Comment: yes, I have tried all the possible way. These were in the initial basic attempts and then I have tried to do some advance thing with mentioned list of solutions.

Comment: What is the file encoding of `logout.php`? Change it to UTF8.

Comment: Will that be applicable in php file? As far as I know it would be for HTML files. How it'll impact in session management?

Comment: Believe me it does. I have faced this issue several times.

Comment: Can you let me know how can I set that encoding? Like putting HTML

Comment: No, no i mean it's the file encoding. If you use Notepad++ take a look here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g7ASyHdCC28 Also try both types: `UTF8` and `UTF8 without BOM` with one of the it will work for sure.

Answer (score 0):

If $_SESSION is used, use unset() to unregister a session variable.

This is the way:

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['user_id'] = '';
$_SESSION['first_name'] = '';
$_SESSION['last_name'] = '';
unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
unset($_SESSION['first_name']);
unset($_SESSION['last_name']);


header("location: /login.php");
exit;
```

Read the warnings and notices here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php

You do not have to call session_destroy() from usual code. Cleanup $_SESSION array rather than destroying session data.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried with this after your suggestion, however it doesn't work :(

Comment: Thank you for sharing a way. I have tried with opcache_reset() however it doesn't work for me yet :(